# Non strictly positive occurrence problem in Coq inductive definition

Tags: coq

The main problem is I cannot define such an Inductive proposition:

```
Inductive forces : nat -> Prop :=
  | KM_cond (n : nat) : ~ forces 0 ->
        forces n.
```

---

In fact, I am trying to define the Kripke Semantics for Intuitionistic Logic

```
Inductive forces (M : Kripke_model) (x : world) : prop -> Prop :=
  | KM_cond (A B : prop) : set_In x (worlds M) ->
      (forall y, (rel M) x y -> (~ forces M y A \/ forces M y B)) ->
        forces M x (A then B).
```

but I get the following error

```
Non strictly positive occurrence of "forces"
```

If I just remove the negation, the problem goes away

```
Inductive forces (M : Kripke_model) (x : world) : prop -> Prop :=
  | KM_cond (A B : prop) : set_In x (worlds M) ->
      (forall y, (rel M) x y -> (forces M y A \/ forces M y B)) ->
        forces M x (A then B).
```

but the problem exists with `->` also

```
Inductive forces (M : Kripke_model) (x : world) : prop -> Prop :=
  | KM_cond (A B : prop) : set_In x (worlds M) ->
      (forall y, (rel M) x y -> (forces M y A -> forces M y B)) ->
        forces M x (A then B).
```

I cannot understand what would possibly go wrong if I define this Inductive thing, and I cannot think of any other way to achieve this definition.

**UPDATE:**

These are the needed definitions:

```
From Coq Require Import Lists.List.
From Coq Require Import Lists.ListSet.
From Coq Require Import Relations.
Import ListNotations.

Definition var := nat.

Inductive prop : Type :=
  | bot
  | atom (p : var)
  | conj (A B : prop)
  | disj (A B : prop)
  | cond (A B : prop).

Notation "A 'and' B" := (conj A B) (at level 50, left associativity).
Notation "A 'or' B" := (disj A B) (at level 50, left associativity).
Notation "A 'then' B" := (cond A B) (at level 60, no associativity).

Definition world := nat.

Definition preorder {X : Type} (R : relation X) : Prop :=
  (forall x : X, R x x) /\ (forall x y z : X, R x y -> R y z -> R x z).

Inductive Kripke_model : Type :=
  | Kripke (W : set world) (R : relation world) (v : var -> world -> bool)
    (HW : W <> empty_set world)
    (HR : preorder R)
    (Hv : forall x y p, In x W -> In y W ->
      R x y -> (v p x) = true -> (v p y) = true).

Definition worlds (M : Kripke_model) :=
  match M with
  | Kripke W _ _ _ _ _ => W
  end.

Definition rel (M : Kripke_model) :=
  match M with
  | Kripke _ R _ _ _ _ => R
  end.

Definition val (M : Kripke_model) :=
  match M with
  | Kripke _ _ v _ _ _ => v
  end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot define this relation as an inductive predicate, but you can define it by recursion on the formula:

```
Fixpoint forces (M : Kripke_model) (x : world) (p : prop) : Prop :=
  match p with
  | bot => False
  | atom p => val M p x = true
  | conj p q => forces M x p /\ forces M x q
  | disj p q => forces M x p \/ forces M x q
  | cond p q => forall y, rel M x y -> forces M y p -> forces M y q
  end.
```

This trick does not work if the definition is not well-founded with respect to the formula structure, but it might be enough for your use case.

Comment: I see, but Inductive types have features like `inversion` and `induction` tactic which are useful in my case (I know I can use induction on my formula). I  also cannot understand why Coq avoids such a definition as an inductive predicate.

Comment: @KamyarMirzavaziri You can probably define an inversion principle for `forces` using a non-recursive inductive predicate. The main issue for defining this as an inductive predicate is that there is probably no good induction principle for it because of the negative occurrences -- sure, we can do induction on the formula `p`, but this is different from doing induction on a proof of `forces M x p`. Do you have a sense of what principle you would like to use?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was thinking about induction on formula also. thanks a lot for your help.